# Trying to add a custom menu to the Wordpress archives.php file

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, insert

I am using the code snippets plug in to avoid changing the template. This is an attempt to insert text, not execute the full menu (which will require php so it only appears on specific Category pages).

```
function addText() {<br />
  'use strict';<br />
  var $group = $('#main');<br />
  $group.prepend('test');<br />
}<br />

addText();<br />
```

When I refresh the page (https://thetomato.ca/tomatoquarantine/category/recipes/), the script appears in the header as expected. However, I get no change at the #main ID. Should happen after 'recipes'.

Comment: Just for context, the following works properly in removing the word “Category: ” from the header text, also as a code snippet, same link (https://thetomato.ca/tomatoquarantine/category/recipes/)
   
`code
function replaceText(target, re, newText) {
   document.querySelectorAll(target).forEach(function(element) {
  element.textContent = element.textContent.replace(re, newText).concat();
   })
 }

 replaceText('.page-header', /Category: $/g, '');`

Comment: Can you improve the readability of your question a bit by explaining what should be the expected outcome?